# Como retornar o ultimo Registro de uma coluna SQL em uma textBox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para meu curso técnico que irá cadastrar clientes, no caso gostaria que antes de cadastrar o cliente o campo código retornasse o ultimo código da tabela sql + 1 para mostrar automaticamente o código que será registrado no cliente que esta sendo cadastrado. se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria muito grato. tentei esse código no form para retornar o valor:

```
private void cad_cliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comando.Connection = conn;
            {
                conn.Open();
                const int i = 1;
                comando.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(cod_cli) FROM cad_cli";
                dr = comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        textBoxCod.Text = "SELECT MAX(cod_cli) FROM cad_cli" + i;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Quando precisas apenas de um valor podes e deves usar o [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2)

O codigo ficaria algo assim:

```
string sql = "SELECT MAX(cod_cli) FROM cad_cli";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sua_connection_string))
{                           
    var comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);       
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int maxId = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
        textBoxCod.Text = (maxId + 1).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: no campo "using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sua_connection_string))" neste "sua_connection_string" eu usei conn no inicio do código, assim : SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=luanpc\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=cliente; Integrated Security=True"); seria "conn" mesmo ?